# Swisscom App Cloud Node version

Tags: node.js, swisscomdev

I would like to use the new EF6 features in my new node.js application.

Where do I find the current supported node version installed in the Swisscom App Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Cloud Foundry command line tool you can list the currently installed build packs:

```
> cf buildpacks
Getting buildpacks...
```

In the output you can find the installed buildpack version for node.js

```
buildpack          | position | enabled | locked | filename                            |
nodejs_buildpack   | 4        | true    | false  | nodejs_buildpack-cached-v1.5.14.zip |
```

the nodejs buildpack github repo contains a [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack/blob/master/CHANGELOG) file where the updates to the buildpacks are maintained. Updates to the Node version are pointed out there.